# How to install NPM application (inside Docker container) that was separated to Git Submodule

Tags: node.js, docker, unix, npm, bitbucket-pipelines

I am facing the problem that i can't beat for about a week. So here is the thing

### Basic description

We have **Yii2** application based on [Basic Yii2 application template](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-basic). It's main app. Our repository is hosted on [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/).

Also we have **Vue.js** application that was installed using [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/) and that is built using [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/). It also has a repository on [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/). This application is basically SPA for Yii2 part and it was added like Git Submodule to that Yii2 part. It located in `/web/client` directory.

We are using **Bitbucket Pipelines** for building and deploy. Pipelines use Docker containers. We have our own repository on Docker Hub that is based on **php:7.2.9** repository (which is based on Debian). So we have full access to it and we can modify or reconfigure it.

Here some simplified deploy process:

1. Bitbucket sets up environment
2. Run `git submodule update --init --recursive` that will clone Vue part of app
3. Installing Yii2 part of application using Composer
4. Installing Vue.js part of application using NPM
5. Removing temp files and sending to server

### Main issue

The issue takes place on 4th step. When we need to install Vue.js part of application. The problem is that root directory is project's root directory. Lets assume it is `/`. It's impossible to run `npm install` and `npm run build` in it.

Also we can't run something like this: `cd ./web/client/`, `npm install`, `npm run build`, `cd ../../` because it's Docker container. So i decided that i can path some parameters to npm command.

I found a couple of solutions but all of them do pretty same thing like `npm install --prefix ./web/client`. It doesn't work and has **ENOLOCAL** error. Also i didn't found anything useful in npm logs.

If i try `npm --prefix ./web/client install ./web/client` everything goes well. But `/web/client` now contains some strange files that probably need to be located in `/web/client/node_modules/.bin`

So the main question how to run `npm install` and `npm run build` in current working directory but built application in another directory (in my case `/web/client`)?

Answer (score 0):

Each Dockerfile `RUN` command is run in its entirety, so you can: `cd ./web/client/`, `npm install`, `npm run build`. You just need to ensure it's done during a single RUN step. Like so:

```
RUN cd ./web/client/ && npm install && npm run build
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I thought about it. I know about RUN, WORKDIR and etc. The thing is that `RUN` executes before **Step 1** - Bitbucket sets up environment, so we don't even know about files existence.